# MVC 5 with REST Security Constraint?

Tags: entity-framework, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I am looking to build an MVC with Entity Framework app so users with proper credentials can enter and edit data. I then want to expose the data via a REST Web Service so a "public facing site" can consume the JSON data. All users of the public facing site need to be able to view the Web service data without needing to login.

If I lock down my MVC site, will that affect the REST API coming from it, or will the REST be "open"? The REST API will be consumed by a totally different site. I need to separate the editors from the Web users.

Thanks!

K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decorate the controller with [AllowAnonymous] attribute. The rest of the MVC controller you need to decorate with the [Authorize] attribute in order to be protected.